# SQL Views (id + count_table1_column1 + count_table2_column_1)

Tags: sql, view

Im doing following query to select out a serialnumber from table Alerts, and then count how many alerts there is for that serialnumber together with the count on how many measurements there also is for that serialnumber. Measurements is stored in another table. (first 2 queries is jsut there to show you the result for better understanding)

```
SELECT InstrumentSerialNumber FROM [dbo].[CloudMeasurements]

SELECT InstrumentSerialNumber FROM [dbo].[CloudAlerts]

SELECT 
DISTINCT InstrumentSerialNumber,  
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CloudAlerts] WHERE [CloudAlerts].InstrumentSerialNumber = InstrumentSerialNumber) AS Alerts,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CloudMeasurements] WHERE [CloudMeasurements].InstrumentSerialNumber = InstrumentSerialNumber) AS Measurements
FROM [CloudAlerts]
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqZE7.png)
See picture for result of the query.
I assume it respond with Count(*) summarized which makes it wrong from my perspective. How do I write this?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try joining the results of their groups:

```
SELECT 
    A.InstrumentSerialNumber,
    A.TotalAlerts,
    ISNULL(M.TotalMeasurements, 0) TotalMeasurements
FROM
    (SELECT InstrumentSerialNumber, COUNT(*) TotalAlerts FROM [CloudAlerts] GROUP BY InstrumentSerialNumber) AS A
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT InstrumentSerialNumber, COUNT(*) TotalMeasurements FROM [CloudMeasurements] GROUP BY InstrumentSerialNumber) 
        AS M ON M.InstrumentSerialNumber = A.InstrumentSerialNumber
```

Comment: I inverted the tables from the FROM clause, now it should display a serial number for each different serial number on CloudAlerts.

Comment: I didnt have sufficient data, but after adding it, it works like a charm!
Thanks for the help!